# file column comparison and appending output in perl

Tags: perl

With my two input file as:

file1.txt as,

```
NP_418770.2
NP_416485.4
```

and file2.txt as,

```
NP_415931.4: 1-8, 29-40, 69-80, 100-111, 124-132
NP_418770.2: 264-293
YP_026226.4: 84-101, 174-182, 208-217, 332-341, 376-388, 593-606
NP_416485.4: 1-18, 16-25, 106-122, 129-153
NP_417679.2: 1-10
NP_417044.4: 1-25, 221-231, 825-836
```

to get only the matched first column values of file1 in file2 and writing output file as (output.txt):

```
NP_418770.2: 264-293
NP_416485.4: 1-18, 16-25, 106-122, 129-153
```

i use awk code as:

```
awk -F: "FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next}; $1 in a {print a[$1]}" file2.txt file1.txt > output.txt
```

now, in a updated situation,with addition to above inputs,  i have two more input files having the same format of file2.txt as:

file3.txt

```
NP_415931.4: 11-88, 59-90, 119-130
NP_418770.2: 254-283
```

and file4.txt

```
NP_418770.2: 24-29, 33-50
NP_416485.4: 1-8, 16-22, 26-32, 39-53
```

and i already have a csv formatted output.csv file as (with header):

```
RefSeq_ID,a,b,c,d,e,f,Go_terms(%)
NP_418770.2,25,83,0,0,0,0,GO:0005887
NP_416485.4,13,19,8,12,0,0,GO:0016878 GO:0051108
```

Now, my question is, how can i append the output of all three input files in the preexisting output.csv? The modified sample output.csv that i want for the above case would be (first line is header):

```
RefSeq_ID,file2_output,file3_output,file4_output,a,b,c,d,e,f,Go_terms
NP_418770.2,264-293,254-283,24-29; 33-50,25,83,0,0,0,0,GO:0005887
NP_416485.4,1-18; 16-25; 106-122; 129-153,,1-8; 16-22; 26-32; 39-53,13,19,8,12,0,0,GO:0016878 GO:0051108
```

(Note that i change the "," in file2,3 and 4 output to ";" so thus not to interfere with format of csv file)

although i try awk for the preliminary case, how can this be done with a perl code?

Comment: Why do you need to switch to Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces almost the output you wanted, only the order of the lines is not always preserved.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

open my $F1, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
my %f1;
while (<$F1>) {
    chomp;
    $f1{$_} = 1;
}

my %output;
my $count = 1;
for my $file (qw( file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt )) {
    open my $F2, '<', $file or die $!;
    while (<$F2>) {
        chomp;
        my @cells = split qr/[,:] /;
        push @{ $output{ $cells[0] } }, [ @cells[ 1 .. $#cells ] ]
            if exists $f1{ $cells[0] };
    }
    @$_ != $count and push @$_, [] for values %output;
    ++$count;
}
open my $F2, '<', 'output.csv' or die $!;
while (<$F2>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $rest) = split /,/, $_, 2;
    push @{ $output{$key} }, [$rest] if exists $f1{$key};
}


for my $k (keys %output) {
    say "$k,", join ',', map { join '; ', @$_ } @{ $output{$k} };
}
```

It creates a hash of arrays keyed by the first column, values from different files are pushed into the inner array in the loop, empty arrays are pushed to missing keys to get the double commas.